# Github java auth with session: what is best way?

Tags: java, api, authentication, github

I tried to use some Java api libraries. But I didn't understand how get token and expires, when I login to Github. For example

```
RepositoryService service = new RepositoryService();
service.getClient().setCredentials("user", "passw0rd");
```

And how get token or session expires? I want to *autoauth* next time

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be better off with Github's [OAuth authentication](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/) mechanism.

With OAuth your application can request a long lived access token that can be used to access resources on the users behalf until the user revokes the permission.

Comment: Ok, I read and used this one. But I didn't understand how can get token, if i know only password and login. In this help talk about access_token as known thing. Do you catch my drift?